# Elastic search integration client in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using elastic search 2.2.3
As described here:

If you’re using Java, the Transport client should be chosen over the Node client unless the performance gain from using a Node client turns out to be large enough to warrant the additional network complexity. Use benchmarks to verify the performance gains.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-interfacing-elasticsearch-picking-client

I heard that on version 5.0 the native client will be dismessd?
Is it true? Which is the best integration client in java? (rest http or native?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elastic Stack is now-available and production-ready with 5.0 versions of Elasticsearch, Kibana, Beats, Logstash, and X-Pack.

The Java API client is still present as you can see at the official docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html

It is extremely fast against the REST HTTP requests, mainly because there is no overhead related to conversions from and to a JSON text, it uses the same binary protocol as the nodes inside the cluster. Yes, ElasticSearch is "just" a Java application.

You can take a look at this [git](https://github.com/dadoonet/legacy-search/blob/06-fuzziness/src/main/java/fr/pilato/demo/legacysearch/dao/ElasticsearchDao.java) repository of the elastic-dev-team, the owner of the repo is one of the evangelist at elastic.co in Paris.

I had the great pleasure to follow one of his live demonstrations and I clearly remember that the speed of "PUTting" documents to an index was about 16'000 documents per second using the TransportClient and BulkProcessor.